# Overlay an image on canvas

Tags: android, android-camera

Is there possible to overlay an image on camera preview butt that image for example a coin should look like an original view, as I will move my camera it will remains in its place just like real objects as seen in camera.

I have done with overlaying a static image on camera preview but that's not my requirement.

please suggest.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to overlay an image up to another image use this method.

```
    public Bitmap overlayChange(Bitmap all, Bitmap scaledBorder) {
    final int width = change.getWidth();
    final int height = change.getHeight();
    all = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(change, width, height, true);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = all.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    scaledBorder = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(border, width, height, true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBorder, 0, 0, null);
    return mutableBitmap;

}
```

and to use it simple

```
yourBitmap = overlayChange(yourBitmap , YourOtherBitmap);
```